# Test Case Suit Execution Error in selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, testng

I have a test suite for 28 test cases(methods) in a single class. Whenever i'm trying to run these methods/ execute test case unexpected no of test cases are getting failed some times error comes in Sleep command some times something else. Error is not constant for any run.

```
     @Test (priority = 5)
  public void AddModule() throws Exception {

     Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(srcCNRegression);
     driver.get(baseUrl1);
     Thread.sleep(5000);
     ModuleLink = driver.findElement(By.linkText("MODULES & INTERVENTIONS"));
     Thread.sleep(5000);
     //HighlightElement.elementHighlight(ModuleLink);
     ModuleLink.click();
     System.out.println(" Module link is open");
     Thread.sleep(5000);
     driver.findElement(By.linkText("Add Modules")).click();
     Thread.sleep(3000);
     // Click on the modules
     driver.findElement(By.name("page:frm:j_id204:1:j_id206")).click();
     Thread.sleep(3000);
     driver.findElement(By.name("page:frm:j_id214")).click(); 
     Thread.sleep(3000);
     System.out.println("Module is added" );

  }
```

Comment: Please share that class code.

Comment: updated the question with a sample piece of code.

Comment: First of all you should not use thread.sleep and use explicit wait instead. That will solve your issue.

Comment: I tried that also. Still its failing.

Comment: what is your question ? and what is the error.

Comment: @Shamik i'm not able to run my test suite in  a single run some or the other test case is getting failed with random error. Some time its stale element error some time element not found.Even if am running the test case with no change

Answer (score 0):

With having a errors occurred , corresponding code  (alone with the web site url you testing if possible) it is hard give a specific answer . But I can give some suggestions

01) Remove Thread.Sleep() , implement wait for specific element

02) Comment out all the test and add one-by-one to isolate specific place you are getting the error . One reason for similar situation is **Application not the state that particular test is expecting** , so even if you see multiple tests getting fail , the actual reason for failing could be in single test